Iterative refinement improving accuracy
Lets say we solve our system $Ax = b$, and our approximate solution $x$ is accurate up to $n$ digits and we calculate our correction term $z$ by solving $Az = r$. Lets say our approximate $z$ is also accurate up to $n$ digits. Why is that when we add $z + x$ our new $x$ is now accurate to $n + n$ digits? When you add two digits each accurate up to $n$ digits the sum is usually only accurate up to $n$ digits also. So why in this case is our $z + x$ now accurate up to $n + n$ digits of our true $x$? I cannot find the reason behind this. Thanks!!

You are assuming that $z$ and $x$ have the same magnitude. Is this so?

Oh I see, yes z is less than in magnitude then x.
